# My jQuery and CSS click-to-toggle menu is acting weird

Tags: jquery, css, menubar

I am having all sorts of weird and wacky problems with my pop-up menu in jQuery.

The menu is supposed to be on a toolbar at the bottom of the window, and pop up when clicked (but not when hovered).
It should then hide again when:
a) a menu item is clicked,
b) the toolbar button that opened it is clicked again,
c) or when anything else is clicked.

This seemed to be working perfectly at first, but it has started to deteriorate. Now, I am left with one heck of a glitch...

Here is what happens:

1. I load the page
2. I click the first menu button. It pops up the menu as it should.
3. I click the second menu button. It pops up and the other one that I left open pops down.
4. Leaving the second one open, I click the first one again. AARGH! The second one stays open! Now they are both open at the same time!??
5. Now I click something in the page to make them go away. Only the first menu goes away! The second one hangs around. To make IT go away, I have to click its menu button.

Please help!!!
Here is my jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xn4TN/31/

Here is my JavaScript:

```
    var togglemenu = null;
    function fn_togglemenu(datatarget) {
        $('.bottom-menu-bg ul li ul[data-target="' + datatarget + '"]').slideToggle(function() {
            togglemenu = $(this).is(':visible') ? datatarget : null;
            $('.bottom-menu-bg ul li ul[data-target="' + datatarget + '"]').parent('li a').toggleClass('hover');
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.bottom-menu-bg ul li a').click(function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();
            fn_togglemenu($(this).attr('data-target'));
        });
        $(document).click(function(ev){
            if(togglemenu != null) {
                fn_togglemenu(togglemenu);
            }
        });
    });
```

There is too much code to include inline realisticly.

Comment: And please consider indenting your code (that way other people can *read* it, and see the structure).

Comment: Sorry about the indentation - I was trying to get it into this site (which I don't know much about!) It was indented to begin with :P

Comment: Also added jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xn4TN/31/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggle isn't hiding the other menus here, so better to be explicit about it. Try this:

```
function fn_togglemenu(datatarget) {
    // hide menus
    $('.bottom-menu-bg ul li ul').hide();
    $('.bottom-menu-bg ul li').removeClass('hover');
    // show target menu
    $('ul[data-target="' + datatarget + '"]').slideToggle(function() {
        $('ul[data-target="' + datatarget + '"]')
            .parent('li a').addClass('hover');
    });
 }

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bottom-menu-bg ul li a').click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.stopPropagation();
        fn_togglemenu($(this).attr('data-target'));
    });

    $(document).click(function(ev) {
        // explicitly hide menus
        $('.bottom-menu-bg ul li ul').hide();
    });
});
```

​

note: also stopped propagation on the link clickhandlers.

Here is your updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/benedict_w/hzHKD/

Comment: Sorry there was a syntax error - I updated the code and the link here: http://jsfiddle.net/benedict_w/hzHKD/ - let me know if it works.